# How to get deb packages for Ubuntu wallpapers

Tags: package-management, 15.04, desktop-background, deb

Where I can found all the desktop wallpapers `deb packages` of all the versions of Ubuntu releases?

However I've found deb package of Ubuntu wallpaper contest 14.04 Trusty Tahr on web previously with URL

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/atareao/+files/trusty-tahr-wallpaper-contest_0.0.1-0extras14.04.0_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i trusty-tahr-wallpaper-contest_0.0.1-0extras14.04.0_all.deb
```

Now I want to install Ubuntu 15.04 wallpapers without a distro-upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a compressed folder with all of the [Ubuntu 15.04 wallpapers here.](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/ubuntu-1504-vivid-vervet-community.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/
2. Search for `wallpaper` and set distribution to `any`

   You should find all available ones correctly named, here direct link for shortcut:

   http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wallpaper&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all